# FactoryGirl and associations validation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I have the following factory setup

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :image do
    title 'Test Title'
    description 'Test Description'
    photo File.new("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/louvre_under_2mb.jpg")
    after(:build) do
      FactoryGirl.build_list(:category, 1)
    end
  end
end
```

Within my model i have these validations

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
  validates :title, presence: { message: "Don't forget to add a title" }
  validates :description, presence: { message: "Don't forget to add a description" }
  validates :categories, presence: { message: 'Choose At Least 1 Category' }
end
```

When I run this test it fails

```
RSpec.describe Image, type: :model do
  it 'should have a valid Factory' do
    expect(FactoryGirl.build(:image)).to be_valid
  end
end

Failure/Error: expect(FactoryGirl.build(:image)).to be_valid
expected #<Image id: nil, title: "Test Title", description: "Test Description", photo_file_name: "louvre_under_2mb.jpg", photo_content_type: "image/jpeg", photo_file_size: 65618, photo_updated_at: "2015-12-15 08:01:07", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to be valid, but got errors: Categories Choose At Least 1 Category
```

Am i approaching this wrong as i was thinking that the validations would not kick in until the whole object was created? or am i thinking about this incorrectly ?

Thanks

Comment: `FactoryGirl.build_list(:category, 1)` builds an array with one category, but neither the array nor the category is associated with the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is in this part.

```
after(:build) do
  FactoryGirl.build_list(:category, 1)
end
```

this will create a list of categories of size 1, but those categories are not associated to the image object. The proper way is as follows:

```
transient do
  categories_count 1
end
after(:build) do |image, evaluator|
  image.categories = build_list(:category, evaluator.categories_count)
end
```

or

```
transient do
  categories_count 1
end
categories { build_list(:category, categories_count) }
```

personally, I would choose this last option.

the `photo` attribute as well is problematique. FactoryGirl is all about flexibility of creating records. But the way you're using it will not present any flexibility, so the photo attribute will be shared between all the records that you'll create using this factory. And sooner or later you'll face some headaches.

so the proper way of creating the `photo` attribute is as follows.

```
transient do
  photo_name 'default_photo.jpg'
end
photo { File.new(File.join(Rail.root, "spec/fixtures", photo_name) }
```

than you can use it this way

```
FactoryGirl.build(:image, photo_name: 'new_photo_name.jpg')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, if i wanted to build a list of categories with `0` categories, so i could fail the building of the object could i just set the `categories_count` to 0 ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using `transient`, real helpful..any thoughts on creating the categories_count at 0 ?

Comment: yes you can just you can do this, `FactoryGirl.build(:image, categories_count: 0)` this will create an image with no categories associated.

Comment: You can just open a `rails console` and play with it.

Comment: ah, so with `transient`, you declare it once in the default image say, and then if i want to change attributes to fail a test (like file name) just use as you have specified, that's very cool and DRY

Comment: yes, exactly that. it makes it more flexible for you to create records. you can read more on transient attributes here https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#transient-attributes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97943/discussion-between-richlewis-and-nafaa-boutefer).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend don't use `after` method in image factory. You should create a correct association. Using this you'll resolve validation error and will't have others problems in the future.

```
class Image
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :image do
    categories_attributes { [FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:category)] }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, could you provide an example please ? I don't just want to hardcode an id here do i? and `photo` is not an associated object

Comment: do you mean like this `categories {[FactoryGirl.build(:category)]}`